# Download random files as zip

Tags: php, html, random, directory

I posted my code a few days back and I am now at this point with it. I have acquired the random files however, when they zip it becomes a zip.cpgz file after unzipping. I am sure that this has something to do with the way I used array in my loop but I am not quite sure of how to fix this.

```
 <?php 
 //./uploads
$dir = "./uploads";
$nfiles = glob($dir.'*.{aiff}', GLOB_BRACE);     
$n=1;
while ($n<=10){
$n ++;
$arr[$n] = rand(2, sizeof($nfiles)-1);
print($arr[$n]);
print("   ");
}


$zip = new ZipArchive();
$zip_name = "zipfile.zip";
if($zip->open($zip_name, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE)!==TRUE){
    $error .= "* Sorry ZIP creation failed at this time";
}

foreach($arr as $file){
    $path = "./uploads".$file;
    $zip->addFromString(basename($path),  file_get_contents($path)); 
}

$zip->close();

header('Content-Type: application/zip');
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename='.$zip_name);
readfile('zipfile.zip');

?>
```

Also if you are kinda lost here is [my website](http://samplepackgenerator.com/) I am trying to implement it on. (click the download button)

Comment: When I tried the download link I got a zip archive with 21 empty files!

Comment: Incidentally - the html on your site is invalid - no closing `a` tag for the `upload` link, `<p class="mbr-footer__copyright"< </p><p>Follow me!` and then a spurious extra `body` tag pair at the bottom...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recently helped another user get something similar to work ( without the random selection ) and you might find the following useful. This does search a directory for a particular file extension and then randomly select 10 files which get zipped and sent. Change the `$sourcedir` and `$ext` to suit - hope it helps.

```
/* From David Walsh's site - modified */
function create_zip( $files = array(), $destination = '', $overwrite = false ) {
    if( file_exists( $destination) && !$overwrite ) { return false; }
    $valid_files = array();
    if( is_array( $files ) ) {
        foreach( $files as $file ) if( file_exists( $file ) ) $valid_files[] = $file;
    }
    if( count( $valid_files ) ) {
        $zip = new ZipArchive();
        if( $zip->open( $destination,$overwrite ? ZIPARCHIVE::OVERWRITE : ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE ) !== true) return false;
        foreach( $valid_files as $file ) $zip->addFile( $file, pathinfo( $file, PATHINFO_FILENAME ) );
        $zip->close();
        return file_exists( $destination );
    }
    return false;
}
/* Simple function to send a file */
function sendfile( $filename=NULL, $filepath=NULL ){
    if( file_exists( $filepath ) ){

        if( !is_file( $filepath ) or connection_status()!=0 ) return FALSE;

        header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
        header("Pragma: no-cache");
        header("Expires: ".gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s", mktime( date("H")+2, date("i"), date("s"), date("m"), date("d"), date("Y")))." GMT");
        header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
        header("Content-Length: ".(string)( filesize( $filepath ) ) );
        header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename={$filename}");
        header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary\n");

        if( $file = @fopen( $filepath, 'rb' ) ) {
            while( !@feof( $file ) and ( connection_status()==0 ) ) {
                print( fread( $file, 1024*8 ) );
                flush();
            }
            @fclose( $file );
        }
        return( ( connection_status()==0 ) and !connection_aborted() );
    }
}



/* Select a random entry from the array */
function pick( $arr ){
    return $arr[ rand( 0, count( $arr )-1 ) ];
}

/* The directory to which the zip file will be written before sending */
$target=__DIR__.'\zipfile.zip';

/* The directory you wish to scan for files or create an array in some other manner */
$sourcedir = 'C:\Temp\temp_uploads';

/* File extension to scan for */
$ext='txt';

/* Placeholder to store files*/
$output=array();

/* Scan the dir, or as mentioned, create an array of files some other way */
$files=glob( realpath( $sourcedir ) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . '*.'.$ext );


/* Pick 10 random files from all possible files */
do{
    $rnd=pick( $files );
    $output[ $rnd ] = $rnd;
}while( count( $output ) < 10 );

/* streamline array */
$output=array_values($output);



if( $target ) {
    /* Zip the contents */
    $result=create_zip( $output, $target, true );

    /* Send the file - zipped! */
    if( $result ) {
        $res=call_user_func( 'sendfile', 'zipfile.zip', $target );
        if( $res ) unlink( $target );
    }
}
```

Comment: you are the man! wow this makes so much more sense to do, apparently my computer is the only one not letting me unzip...is it working for you?

Comment: I could download the zip file but all 21 files were empty and now I'm getting `Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in /home/ghostx19/public_html/phDownloader.php on line 47`

Comment: how should i fix this error..i apologize i am still learing

Comment: The zipfile still contains empty files but it appears the speed issue has been resolved and there are no errors now regarding max execution time. Are you still facing issues?

Comment: im just not sure why the files are empty. is the array just saving a name or something?

Comment: the speed issue stopped because i didnt use your code. if you use the developer tools and look at my download button that is the code i am using.  i think it is just not saving the file correctly.  thanks for all the help by the way

Answer (score 1):

You sure it doens't work? I've donwloaded your zip file and extracted it and I got UploadsX files. So I don't get a zip.cpgz file.